# Can i achieve single sign on with openid

Tags: single-sign-on, openid

I have been reading a lot on Single Sign on and OpenId
I have checked the documentation for OpenId and Single Sign On on the below Link

**Single Sign On**

http://rashidi.zin.my/geek-talks/2009/06/30/php-mysql-curl-single-sign-on-with-multiple-domains.html
http://www.opengroup.org/security/sso/sso_intro.htm
http://www.authenticationworld.com/Single-Sign-On-Authentication/
http://merbist.com/2012/04/04/building-and-implementing-a-single-sign-on-solution/
https://wiki.queensu.ca/display/itsd/Single+Sign-On
https://github.com/jasny/sso#readme
https://lw.microstrategy.com/msdz/MSDL/940/docs/mergedProjects/websdk/topics/sso/SSO_Single_Sign-on.htm

**OpenId**

http://openidexplained.com/
http://openid.net/pres/protocolflow-1.1.png -- Flow Diagram
http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/12995226/Run%20your%20own%20identity%20server

**Simple concept what i understood on Single Sign on can be explained as below**

User hits domain1.com.
domain1.com sees there's no session cookie.
domain1.com redirects to sso.com
sso.com presents login page, and take credentials
sso.com sets session cookie for the user
sso.com then redirects back to domain1 to a special url (like domain1.com/ssologin)
the ssologin URL contains a parameter that is basically "signed" by the sso.com. It could be as simple as a base64 of encrypting the loginid using a shared secret key.
domain1.com takes the encrypted token, decrypts it, uses the new login id to log in the user.
domain1 sets the session cookie for the user.

Now, the next case.

User hits domain2.com, which follows domain1 and redirects to sso.com
sso.com already has a cookie for the user, so does not present the login page
sso.com redirects back to domain2.com with the encrypted information
domain2.com logs in the user.

**OpenId Concept what I got can be explained as**

OpenID allows you to use an existing account to sign in to multiple websites, without needing to create new passwords.
An OpenID is a way of identifying yourself no matter which web site you visit.

Now My problem is even after reading a lot of documentation, am not sure will i be able to achieve single sign on using openID and this is very important for me to know before i start my code.
Is there any way where i can upload my database to OpenId for Authentication, So my users do not need to go through all the drill again.

I will really appreciate if anyone has implemented this earlier or has any reference for me to make this clear

Answer (score 1):

Yes, OpenID will give you single signon across web applications that may live in different domains. Note that OpenID 2.0 (which is the subject of the links that you point to) was deprecated and followed up by OpenID Connect, see: http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Introduction

There are a number of product and libraries that you can use to build on:
http://openid.net/developers/libraries/

Comment: @Hanz Z- Thanks for the reply, I have been through the link you have provided. Even i have checked the PHP lib for which i need to implement but there are many question for which i don't have answer. After getting the library from where i can get the client ID and Secret how this will be called, Am trying to implement in small application for testing before going ahead.

Comment: @Hanz And most important it is no where mention in the document for the single sign on.